# What is the use of Cancellation token here

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task, resharper

I've the following chunk of code :

```
using (var cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource()) 
{
    Task[] tasks = null;

    var cancelToken = cancelSource.Token;
    tasks = new[]
    {
        Task.Run(async () => await ThrowAfterAsync("C", cancelToken, 1000)) //<---
    };
    await Task.Delay(howLongSecs * 1000); // <---
    cancelSource.Cancel();
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Where `ThrowAfterAsync` have this :

```
private async Task ThrowAfterAsync(string taskId, CancellationToken cancelToken, int afterMs)
{
    await Task.Delay(afterMs, cancelToken);
    var msg = $"{taskId} throwing after {afterMs}ms";
    Console.WriteLine(msg);
    throw new ApplicationException(msg);
}
```

Resharper is suggesting me that I can use the overload of `Task.Run()` with cancellation token like this :

```
Task.Run(async () => await ThrowAfterAsync("C", cancelToken, 1000), cancelToken)
```

But why ? What is the benefit of doing this over the first version, without the cancellation token as parameter ?

Comment: Your "chunk of code" seems like it has some bugs; which will happen first, the throw or the cancellation?

Comment: Also, you don't have to take all the advice that Resharper gives you.  I frequently do not.

Comment: My code has a try/catch block around it I just removed that.

Comment: OK, but what is the purpose of throwing after 1000 msecs, while simultaneously cancelling after 1000 msecs?

Comment: It's just for exercise purposes I want to see how things works..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this specific case, there is no point.  In general, you'd want to do as it suggests because, by passing the token to `Task.Run` it can avoid even scheduling the operation in the first place if the token is cancelled before the operation even has a chance to *start*, but in your case you're creating the token and you *know* it won't be cancelled when you start the operation.

But the reason you don't need to pass the token to `Task.Run` is because the code starting that task *is the operation responsible for cancelling the token*, and so it knows that the token isn't cancelled yet.  Normally you'd be accepting a token from elsewhere, and you wouldn't know if/when it was cancelled.

All that said, there's no reason to even use `Task.Run` *at all*.  You can just write:

```
tasks = new[] { ThrowAfterAsync("C", cancelToken, 1000) };
```

It will have the same behavior but without needlessly starting a new thread just to start the asynchronous operation.

Next, your code *will never return in less than `howLongSecs` seconds*, even if the operation finishes before then, because of how you've structured your code.  You should simply provide the timeout to the cancellation token source and let it take care of canceling the token at the right time, it won't delay the rest of your method if the operation finishes before the cancellation should happen, so your whole method can just be written as:

```
using (var cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource(Timespan.FromSeconds(howLongSecs))) 
{
    await ThrowAfterAsync("C", cancelToken, 1000)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast and descriptive answer !

Comment: This is how the original code looked [like](http://prntscr.com/dpslkv) with the edits you pointed. If this explains some of the strange things in the code, I thought that they are redundant but apparently they are not .

Comment: @dB.Employee Having multiple tasks passed to `WhenAll` is apparently actually used, as you have two actual operations.  None of the rest is needed, and the empty `catch` is actively harmful.

Answer (score 2):

Resharper sees that you are using a method (`Task.Run`) which has overload which accepts `CancellationToken`, you have instance of `CancellationToken` in scope, but you do not use that overload which accepts a token. It does not perform any extensive analysys of your code - it's as simple as that. You can easily verify this with this code:

```
class Program {
    static void Main() {
        CancellationToken ct;
        Test("msg"); // will suggest to pass CancellationToken here
    }

    private static void Test(string msg) {

    }

    private static void Test(string msg, CancellationToken ct) {

    }
}
```

Yes the code itself is strange and you don't need to wrap your async in `Task.Run` at all, but I won't touch that since you asked just why Resharper suggests that.